# node json request stack

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi everyone I know my question is very easy buy i'm new using json.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
function myCon(sql){

var con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "127.0.0.1",
        port: "3306",
        user: "root",
        password: "xxxxxx",
        database: "myDataBase",
    });
     // here i'm passing sql query  as var sql
con.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
    if (err) { throw err }
    else {
           console.log(rows);
           // here I want my response to be json response eg { key:value}
       }
 })
con.end();
}

module.exports.con = myCon;
```

the result is

```
[ RowDataPacket { countryId: 1, countryName: 'N/A' },
  RowDataPacket { countryId: 2, countryName: 'UK' },
  RowDataPacket { countryId: 3, countryName: 'USA' },
  RowDataPacket { countryId: 4, countryName: 'UAE' } ]
```

i want the response to be as

```
  { countryId: 1, countryName: 'N/A' },
  { countryId: 2, countryName: 'UK' },
  { countryId: 3, countryName: 'USA' },
  { countryId: 4, countryName: 'UAE' }
```

with out RowDataPacket
and resend it to ejs view

Comment: Your result looks like invalid javascript, is that really what you're getting in the log

Comment: yes i'm passing sql from other js file   var country = mysql.con('select countryId,countryName from country');

Comment: Which MySQL module are you using?

Answer (score 5):

```
[ 
  RowDataPacket { countryId: 1, countryName: 'N/A' },
  RowDataPacket { countryId: 2, countryName: 'UK'  },
  RowDataPacket { countryId: 3, countryName: 'USA' },
  RowDataPacket { countryId: 4, countryName: 'UAE' } 
]
```

This is how the console displays the results, as the data returned from MySQL is of type `RowDataPacket`, but what you've actually got is just the object you want, you don't have to do anything really.

If you really want to get rid of the types, you can do

```
con.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
    if (err) { 
        throw err 
    } else {
        var str = JSON.stringify(rows);
        rows = JSON.parse(str);

        console.log(rows);
    }
});
```

Comment: the result undefined

Comment: @HussainAli - try it like above

Comment: thank you Deneo i got the point so now i can  pass data as json to the view using for each with key and value